# ElasticSearch ajax request always returns the same result

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, jsonp

I am trying to query ElasticSearch using ajax, but I am getting the same result always, even if I change the query it remains same. Seems like the match part is not getting executed. Because if I add more field like release date, I am getting that data.

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Search Result!</h1>
        <br />
        <input id="searchterm" />
    <button id="search">search</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
      $("#search").click(function(e){
        var data = {
                query:{match:{_all:$('#searchterm').val()}},
                pretty: true,
                fields: '_id'
                };

                alert(JSON.stringify(data));

              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:9200/movies/_search',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                type: 'POST',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: data,
               success: function(data) {
                  //alert(""+JSON.parse(data.hits.total));
                  $("#results").empty();
                  $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + $("#searchterm").val() + "</b></p>");
                  $.each(data.hits.hits, function(i,item){
                    $("#results").append("<div><a href='#'>" + item._id + "</a></div>");
                  });
                }
              });
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

Search Result!

Results for **furious**

Insurgent (2015)

Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens (2015)

Ant-Man (2015)

Jurassic World (2015)

Cinderella (2015)

Daredevil (2003)

Get Hard (2015)

Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)

Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice (2016)

Home (2015)

The result is not relevant to the entered keyword, the output should be all the movies that contains furious in the movie name. But, still I am getting first 10 movies.

Any suggestion could be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

I got this thing to work, I have listed the Changes below:

1. Change jsonp to json
2. Added contentType: 'application/json' in ajax request
3. Remove the pretty: true from data, as it was giving parsing error.
4. Change data format to JSON.stringify(data)

Analyzed this by monitoring the request header in chrome developer tool.

Here is the working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Search Result!</h1>
        <br />
        <input id="searchterm" />
    <button id="search">search</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
      $("#search").click(function(e){
        var data = {
                query:{match:{_all:$('#searchterm').val()}},
                fields: '_id'
                };

                alert(JSON.stringify(data));

              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:9200/movies/_search',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
               success: function(data) {
                  //alert(""+JSON.parse(data.hits.total));
                  $("#results").empty();
                  $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + $("#searchterm").val() + "</b></p>");
                  $.each(data.hits.hits, function(i,item){
                    $("#results").append("<div><a href='#'>" + item._id + "</a></div>");
                  });
                }
              });
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps somebody.